# How to select thousands of lines

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with 200,000 lines. How do I select multiple lines, before I delete them?

Manual work is too difficult for, say, 65,000 lines.

Comment: select them by what criteria? You'd have better luck using a regex or such, but without more information its hard to give a specific, useful answer

Comment: Continuous or seperated lines?

Comment: CTRL+mouse select can do something like what you want to do.

Comment: Click on the starting line, scroll down to the ending line, hold the shift key, and click again.

Comment: YES !  Tank you DanH, shift key is the solution !!

Comment: I answered this question here http://superuser.com/a/405539/120206 . if you just want to mark thousands lines, in the answer don't delete lines in macro after marking them.

Answer (score 10):

**Easiest way:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, go to line 1

```
    Menu > Edit > Begin/End select.
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, go to line 65.000.

```
    Menu > Edit > Begin/End select.
```

**You now have your range selected.**

Answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490968/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>some direction control</kbd> combo is pretty darned slow for thousands of lines/pages; so here's a *fast* solution...

```
# File:: selectGOTO.py
#   A N++ Python Script to enhance line selection speed compared to mouse, cursor, page controls.
#   Selects text from the [ start|end ] of current line to [ end|start ] of GOTO line.

# Install using:: Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Python Script
# Create script using:: Plugins -> Python Script -> New Script -> "selectGoto.py"
# Add to menu:: Plugins -> Python Script -> Configuration -> [select script] [ add ]
# Create shortcut:: [Restart N++]
#   Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin Commands -> selectGOTO -> [modify] [ctrl]+[shift]+[g]

# Simple usage:
#   [ctrl]+[shift]+[g] line#
#   Do your operation... (ie: del)

from Npp import *

class startAnchor:
    pos = 0

def selectGOTO( args ):
    endPos = editor.getCurrentPos()
    if( endPos > startAnchor.pos ):
        startAnchor.pos = editor.positionFromLine( editor.lineFromPosition( startAnchor.pos ) )
    else:
        tmp = startAnchor.pos
        startAnchor.pos = endPos
        endPos = tmp
    endPos = editor.getLineEndPosition( editor.lineFromPosition( endPos ) )
    editor.setSel( startAnchor.pos, endPos )
    editor.clearCallbacks()

def main():
    startAnchor.pos = editor.getCurrentPos()
    editor.callback( selectGOTO, [SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.UPDATEUI] )
    notepad.menuCommand( MENUCOMMAND.SEARCH_GOTOLINE )

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Holding Shift and PageDown can select multiple lines fairly quickly.

Comment: Ctrl + A selects everything in the document. This question was about selecting multiple lines, not the entirety of the document.