# Selecting range of lines in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

How do I select specific range of lines in Notepad++ quickly? I have a text file that has over 1M of lines and I need to delete some fragments from it, but selecting lines manually just takes too much time. For example: I need to select lines from 2000 to 12000, how to make it quick?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8490968/1469208) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a better answer. You could record a macro ( deleting for example `10` lines ) . Then run it several times .

1) Go to `Macro > Start recording`

2) hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and tap <kbd>Down</kbd> to mark for example `10` lines . And delete them.

3) Go to `Macro > Stop Recording`

Now your macro is recorded, you can save it for using in the future .

4) Go to `Macro > Save Current Recording Macro...` . And save it with a name .

5) Move cursor to line that you want to delete lines after that.Then go to `Macro > Run A Macro Multiple Times...` . And select your macro and run it `N` times that you want.

Comment: That's an idea! This may work, thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 9):

Just <kbd>Left Click</kbd> once in line `2000` .then go to line `12000` , hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> again .

1) <kbd>Left Click</kbd> in line `2000`

2) Go to line `12000`

3) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> in line `12000`

Comment: Yeah, but I lose selection with ctrl+G. That's what I'm talking about, going from 2000 to 12000 takes ages.

Answer (score 3):

I had just responded with this in [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/390021/how-to-select-thousands-of-lines/484116#484116), but it looks like a more fitting answer for here, and I'm guessing that this Question Title would get more hits...  so, I'm posting here and hoping it isn't some kind of faux pas... (perhaps it should just be a link to the other?)

```
# File:: selectGOTO.py
#   A N++ Python Script to enhance line selection speed compared to mouse, cursor, page controls.
#   Selects text from the [ start|end ] of current line to [ end|start ] of GOTO line.

# Install using:: Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Python Script
# Create script using:: Plugins -> Python Script -> New Script -> "selectGoto.py"
# Add to menu:: Plugins -> Python Script -> Configuration -> [select script] [ add ]
# Create shortcut:: [Restart N++]
#   Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin Commands -> selectGOTO -> [modify] [ctrl]+[shift]+[g]

# Simple usage:
#   [ctrl]+[shift]+[g] line#
#   Do your operation... (ie: del)

from Npp import *

class startAnchor:
    pos = 0

def selectGOTO( args ):
    endPos = editor.getCurrentPos()
    if( endPos > startAnchor.pos ):
        startAnchor.pos = editor.positionFromLine( editor.lineFromPosition( startAnchor.pos ) )
    else:
        tmp = startAnchor.pos
        startAnchor.pos = endPos
        endPos = tmp
    endPos = editor.getLineEndPosition( editor.lineFromPosition( endPos ) )
    editor.setSel( startAnchor.pos, endPos )
    editor.clearCallbacks()

def main():
    startAnchor.pos = editor.getCurrentPos()
    editor.callback( selectGOTO, [SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.UPDATEUI] )
    notepad.menuCommand( MENUCOMMAND.SEARCH_GOTOLINE )

main()
```

Comment: Great! I've been looking for that for ages. However I edited your code so it doesn't move the initial selection point - there's no need to. (Removed code after if( endPos > startAnchor.pos )).

Comment: I also created extra versions that select to Previous Bookmark (command 43007) and Next Bookmark (43006) that suit me better.

Answer (score 1):

1)click ctrl + g give the line number to go suppose 2000
2)Right click then select Begin/End option
3)click ctrl + g give the line number to go suppose 10000
4)Right click then select Begin/End option
5)Ctrl + c to copy