# notepad++ the Option to Begin/End select is not there

Tags: notepad++

I need to select a range of 200,000 lines from a file and I found this post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161262/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad
The only issue is the option to Begin/End select is not there, not when I right click, not under the Edit tab. I am at a complete loss as searching on google it seems like no one else has ever had this problem.

Comment: On version [8.4.5](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (64 bit), it is under the Edit menu. What version are you using?

Comment: There is also [another post here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/405522/selecting-range-of-lines-in-notepad) about it. Did you check it?

Comment: Please, don't [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73696357/372239). Delete one of the question.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado This is probably the problem, I guess my work has the licensee for 5.6.6

Comment: There are no licences mandatory for Notepad++. You can upgrade it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permission to do that on my system, I'll see if my IT team can do that for me, but I'm glad I know the issue now

Comment: @KillMe553 - please delete this question and come back after Notepad++ was updated by your IT Team with a new question. OR answer by yourself after Notepad++ was updated. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].